# If Controller is not working as expected

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

I am working on a JMeter script and trying to get response time from a sampler, store it into a variable, and then user IF Controller in tear down thread group on the basis of response time i.e. send an email if response time is greater than 300 milliseconds.

I have stored response time as follows using `Beanshell post processor`

`long duration = prev.getTime();
vars.put("duration", String.valueOf(duration));`

And trying to trigger email sampler under IF Controller using following condition:

`${duration} > '300'`

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Variables cannot be shared between threads. Use property to store duration, and you will be able to use it in tearDown Thread Group.

```
long duration = prev.getTime();
props.put("duration", String.valueOf(duration));
```

After that you can use:

> ${__P(duration,0)}

"Zero" is place for default value in case property with given name is not found.

---

Btw, you could also use Beanshell/Groovy to get property:

> vars.put("durationVariable", props.get(duration));

Comment: Thanks - it helped and my script is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors there:

1. Variables are local to the current Thread Group only, if you need to pass them between Thread Groups you need to convert them into JMeter Properties (see [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) for details) or use [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) for the same, example code:

   ```
   long duration = prev.getTime();
   bsh.shared.duration = duration
   ```
2. Surrounding number with quotation marks is wrong as JavaScript will treat it as a String, you don't need quotation marks there. Also you can use [__Beanshell() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) as the If Controller clause like:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.duration > 300)}
   ```

---

Also be aware that duration is in **milliseconds** so maybe your 300 ms threshold might be a little bit low.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. I wasn't aware that variables are local to thread groups. Will try this now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by using properties as they can be shared among thread groups.

Thanks all